# What Did Lyanna Stark Say to Ned Stark?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the final episode of season 6 we see that Lyanna Stark is whispering something to Ned. What is she saying?

Comment: "Rosebud......"

Comment: "Delete my browsing history......Promise me Ned"

Comment: "There is another Targaryen"?

Comment: "Don't tell anyone, it'll drive the fans crazy.... Promise me Ned"

Comment: "He must know nothing...Promise me Ned"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**She probably says Jon, but there is no way to know for sure.**

You may be thinking you failed to catch that line, but the producers made sure it is not audible after "his name is...". But "If Robert finds out, he'll kill him." points out to the child being a Targeryen. The face of the baby fading into adult Jon makes us believe he is Jon.

Comment: Source for the producers making sure it wasn't audible?

Comment: It was missing in the subtitles.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I think everyone who have seen the show are eye witness in this case.

Comment: It looked like a two syllable word to me - upon rewatching a couple of times, possibly 'Eddard'.   
However, there's no guarantee that Ned would have kept the child under their given name (especially if it's also his name, given the whole 'bastard' thing and the Stark's insistence on honour)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense for Lyanna to have named the kid Jon. It makes much more sense for that to be a name Ned chooses, naming the kid after Jon Arryn - who, now I come to think about it, was like a father to Ned (and Robert) but wasn't his actual father... like Ned and Jon Snow... hmm...

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think you mean ear-witness, its a little hard to be eye-witness to a sound :p

Comment: @user568458 How do we know Jon is not named for Jon Connington, a very close friend of Prince Rhaegar? It would make sense that Rhaegar wanted to name his son after Lord Jon Connington and Ned just pretended that he was instead named after Jon Arryn. Of course not implying that he came back from the dead to name Jon, he could have told Lyanna about his wishes on naming the child

Comment: @Aegon naming a bastard of someone who respect is unseen. It is, in many ways, insulting. Remember, Lollys planned to name her bastard out of rape as Tywin but Cersei got furious?  I think Ned naming him from Jon Arryn is absurd. Jon Connington makes much more sense. After all, Rhaegar had a say in that. In fact, Lyanna tells Ned, "the name of our baby is...", which makes me believe she named him with Rhaegar. I know this evidence is circumstantial, however, it is clear that he wasn't named after Jon Arryn by Ned.

Comment: Oh Cersei was a total b*tch plus the Child of Lollys was born out of Rape so it was indeed very insulting. Jon loved Eddard like a son and Eddard loved him back. Pretty sure he wouldn't mind having a son of Eddard named after him. I also believe the babe was named after Lord Conington by Rhaegar, not after Lord Arryn by Eddard.

Comment: @Aegon Why not name his firstborn Jon to show this respect? Or the ones after that? Why would you name a bastard who is not worthy of your surname after a worthy person that you respect?

Comment: I realise that Lyanna assuming that Robert will kill Jon is meant to imply that Rhaegar is the father and I'm not saying that he isn't. But it's possible that Lyanna believed that Robert would kill the baby just because it was a child that Lyanna had with someone other than himself.

Answer (score 5):

In the final episode of Season 7 (The Dragon and the Wolf), we get so see another flashback of this scene through Bran. This version makes it very clear what Lyanna says. She tell's Ned that her son's name is Aegon Targaryen.

"his name is Aegon, Aegon Targaryen"

I'll have to double check the exact phrasing later when I can rewatch the episode.

Answer (score 3):

The scene purposefully makes Lyanna's comment inaudible to leave the suspense of the revelation of what she says. All the transcripts I could find also appear to omit this part:

> LYANNA: Please. Listen to me, Ned.
>   
> *LYANNA whispers in NED’s ear.*
>   
> LYANNA: If Robert finds out, he’ll kill him, you know he will. You have to protect him. Promise me, Ned. Promise me.
>   
> <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 6 Episode 10, "The Winds of Winter"</sub>

However, as of Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf", this has now been answered.

> His name is Aegon Targaryen. You have to protect him. Promise me, Ned.
>   
> <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf"</sub>